# How to store svn change history in local machine?

Tags: svn

Is there a way I could copy the svn change history to my local machine?
I am not able to do look history (which I have to do pretty frequently) when net connection is bad (which is happening lot of times lately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The many DVCS have support to act as subversion clients.

- Mercurial: [hgsubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) (I can recommend this one)
- Git: [git-svn](http://andy.delcambre.com/2008/03/04/git-svn-workflow.html)
- Bazaar: [bzr-svn](https://launchpad.net/bzr-svn)

There is also [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage), a dedicated svn cache.

*edit*

You need to be aware that you need a rebase-based workflow with these DVCS tools, since they can't transmit their native merges into subversion.

Comment: But these are themselves SCM servers, right? Aren't there any other tools that just stores history?

Comment: @Reddy Mercurial, Git and Bazaar use an in-place repository along with the working copy (juts like svn does with the .svn folders everywhere, but with the full project history instead of the local checkout). They do not require to set up a server.

Comment: no server is because these are distributed and every client acts as server as well?
I will try one of them. Thanks.

Comment: @reddy The main point about a dvcs is that everything is local. When you commit files, the new commit is placed in the local repo at the top-level directory of your working copy. There are only servers involved when you want to publish your commits, or fetch commits from others (more precise: when you need query a remote repo or push data into it). Se also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377700/which-git-commands-cannot-be-executed-locally

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I will try hgsubversion first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn), as long as you are comfortable (or are willing to get comfortable) with using git to access the history.  FWIW, I find git to be a much more pleasant way to query history anyway.