# Which Git commands cannot be executed locally?

Tags: git

When I talk to colleagues about Git, I tell them, that there are only three Git commands that cannot be executed without going to a remote repository once a local repo is initialized (assuming that `origin` is not on the local machine, of course):

- [`git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html)
- [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)
- [`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

Just to make sure that I didn't miss something: are there any other commands that need a connection to a remote repository?

Comment: If your origin repository is on the same computer, even those can work locally :-)

Comment: @Paŭlo: Good point. Updated question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git clone
git ls-remote
git remote prune
git remote show
git remote update
git submodule update
git request-pull
```

... ...

Also many `git svn` subcommands require an external Subversion repository.

There are several "plumbing" commands that require an external repository, but in the context of introducing colleagues to git, it's probably only worth listing the "porcelain" commands like those above.

Comment: I assume, that `git log origin/master` also fires up a connection.

Comment: @Boldewyn: You assume incorrectly. `git log` only operates on the local repository.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you need a `git fetch`, before the log is displayed up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

`git remote update` and `git remote show ${REMOTE}` will also need to connect to the remote.

Answer (score 1):

`git request-pull` also would like to connect to a (potentially remote) repository.

Comment: Added it to the wiki answer. Thanks.