# Git cli pull request - no PR created in the remote repo

Tags: git, gitea, tekton, tekton-pipelines

After creating a git pull request by CLI, it is not visible in the remote repo. Should I use another push request to update the remote (Gitea) repo?

Context is a **Tekton pipeline**. I have to work with the command line interface or a Tekton task. The existing PR Tekton task is for GitHub or Gitlab.I work here with a Gitea repo.

First I create a branch 'prod' from the 'master' branch, edit a change, commit the change and push it to the remote repo. Works of course fine.

Then I start a pull request like this:

```
git request-pull master http://remote-repo.git prod
```

For more info see [this official doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull).

In the remote repo the new pull request is not visible. How come?

Do I have to push any branch to the remote repo?

I tried to use origin/master as a parameter, but that is an invalid 'revision'.

Comment: Please be aware that `git request-pull` has nothing to do with git hosting services. It creates a local summary of all the changes.

Comment: Use the gitea cli https://docs.gitea.com/administration/command-line

Comment: Git commands do not affect gitlab, gitea, github, etc, services. Use their CLI (if they exist). All git commands are local, besides a few exceptions.

Comment: Git clone, pull, push, merge work fine remotely. What about them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377700/which-git-commands-cannot-be-executed-locally only these commands interact with a remote. Even then they do not have anything to do with gitea, gitlab, github, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few options:

- Any 'git' remote command: alas, git request-pull does not create a remote pull request.
- A Tekton (Hub) standard task: there is an existing Pullrequedst task, but it interacts only with Github or Gitlab.
- Using the Gitea API: that one works! Checked it with a CI/CD expert.

You can find sufficient information via http://your-gitea-server/api/swagger.

As an example:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://try.gitea.io/api/v1/repos/pr_api_test/pr_test/pulls?token=apersonalaccesstoken' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "base": "main",
  "head": "content",
  "title": "first pr",
  "body": "This is a PR!"
}'
```